# Serial Port Connection - Only works with breakpoints

Tags: c#, serial-port

**The Problem**

I have a serial port connection used to control a lamp.

The problem I'm having is that it seems to work every so often but works consistently in debug mode when
I run through with breakpoints.

**What I've tried**

I have tried adding in delays to allow connections to take place after initalizing the port

```
await Task.Delay(model.TimeIntervel);
```

**Code**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> RunExperiment(ExperimentViewModel model)
    {

        if (model.Intensity > 250)
        {
            TempData["BadMsg"] = "Intensity value is out of range. Please try again with a value between 0 W/m2 and 250 W/m2";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        if (model.TimeIntervel <= 0)
        {
            TempData["BadMsg"] = "Time interval value is out of range. Please try again with a value >0 in ms";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        if (model.TimeIntervel <= 0 && model.Intensity > 250)
        {
            TempData["BadMsg"] = "Time interval value is out of range. Please try again with a value >0 in ms. Intensity value is out of range. Please try again with a value between 0 W/m2 and 250 W/m2";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        #region Port Set Up
        //Set up the port 
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 57600, (Parity)0, 8, (StopBits)1);
        //Set Flow Control to none
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        //Open Port
        port.Open();
        #endregion

        if (model.AllLamps == true)
        {

            //Set Logic From Form
            port.Write("gintensity " + model.Intensity + " \r");
            port.Write("genable \r");

            //Set Time Delay
            await Task.Delay(model.TimeIntervel);

            //Turn Off Lamp/Lamps
            port.Write("gdisable \r");
        }
        else {

            //Set Logic From Form for individual lamp
            port.Write("w "+model.LampID+"m1 " + model.Intensity + " \r");
            port.Write("w "+model.LampID+"m1 enable \r");

            //Set Time Delay
            await Task.Delay(model.TimeIntervel);

            //Turn Off all Lamp/Lamps
            port.Write("gdisable \r");

        }

      

        //Close Port
        port.Close();

        //Successful Experiment Message
        TempData["GoodMsg"] = "Experiment Ran Successfully";

        //Return to Form
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Where do you need to put a breakpoint to make it working? How this method is called, i.e. what happens after that?

Comment: _"seems to work"_ - so, I read this as "does what it is supposed to do". But what is it supposed to do? What do you expect this code to do, that you are or are not seeing?

Comment: ^^ Because: If I were to guess, then I'd say you are switching so fast on and off, that you  probably don't see the signal on your lamp without breakpoint. Then if you step through and have high signal for several seconds, well that would be rather obvious if the lamp is on or off ...

Comment: I put the breakpoint at the start of the method and run through with f10. The action opens the serial port, writes commands and then closes the port and redirects to a view.

Comment: Adding delays into serial port code make no sense.  It creates more problems.  You should always use Asyn Read for serial port because the Window Library has timers that are unreliable.  Many people attempt to add timers and use the Synchronous Read method but I've never found that to work 100%.

Comment: Unrelated: Have a look at [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) (not affiliated)

Comment: @Fildor I require the lamps to turn on for a certain amount of time based on user input. I can see the lamps turn on and that is how I know it has worked

Comment: I'd also highly recommend you abstract the "Lamp-Code" away into a Service, so you can actually Unit-Test it.

Comment: Well, you allow anything >0ms. A value close to 0ms might not even turn the lamp on (depending on circuitery and the lamp itself) even if the signal is high.

Comment: Also, mind that you are not on a real-time system. If your controlling electronics have real-time capabilities, it would be advisable to use timing facilities on their side.

Comment: @Fildor Okay, I get that. We are usually have times of about 3000-10000 ms.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable, yes.

Comment: Have you also checked intensity? There may be a threshold which - if value is below it - the lamp may not be perceived as "on".

Comment: @Fildor apologies, its the first time I've used serial connection so my knowledge is lacking. I want to take a users input for lamp intensity and time intervel, and then write commands to the lamp through serial port so the lamp turns on at that intensity for that length of time.

Comment: @Fildor Yes. We most often use 10 for intensity and its clearly visible with the lamps

Comment: Ok, so now we have ruled that out, back to jdweng's comment... :)

Comment: @jdweng So what is the best way to write commands to the lamps? I have it in an async action.

Comment: First the term "Not working" is misleading.  The serial port is working fine.  We have a System issue that the lamp does not turn on instantly, and the human eye cannot see light with very short duration.  So you need to have delays for lamp turn on and turn off times.  This has nothing to do with the serial port not working.

Comment: @jdweng yeah okay, I can see that the serial port is working and the connection is established. Why am I having issue writing command to the lamps? My thinking was the commands need enough time to execute hence why I added the delay. What is a better approach?

Comment: You only posted client code.  What does the server code look like?